# Custom Element (HTMLElement) allowed as child of list (<ul> and <ol>)?

Tags: html, tags, web-component, semantic-markup, custom-element

I figure this is not allowed:

```html
<ul>
  <my-li>
    #shadow-root
    <li>
      <span>hello!</span>
    </li>
  </my-li>
</ul>
```

But what can we do to not break semantics? I know that elements other than `HTMLElement` would exist, but Safari is not okay with this being the case. What would be the best solution to achieve a proper HTML semantic?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom elements can customize existing elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#customized_built-in_elements). If you're wanting to create a custom list item element, you should probably extend the existing one. This will allow you to validly place it as a child of an unordered list element.

When you're constructing a custom element, you can tell it to extend an existing element like so:

```js
class MyLI extends HTMLLIElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    ...
  }
}

customElements.define('my-li', MyLI, { extends: 'li' })
```

To use it, you would still use a regular, semantic, syntactically correct list item element, but you tell the browser it's an instance of a custom element with the `is` attribute.

```html
<ul>
  <li is="my-li">
    #shadow-root
    <span>hello!</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I implicitly mentioned in the question that Safari does not support that sadly. :(

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for validating on semantic use of HTML elements, then you can do that [here](http://validator.w3.org/)